# Is there a way to manually start and stop streams?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a stream that generates Random numbers. My purpose here is to "Start" and "Stop" the random number generation stream at will. I want to utilize the StreamBuilder widget as well.

StreamBuilder should stream the random number generator stream say "Stream X", the "Start" and "Stop" buttons should start and stop (emit and stop emitting the values) the "Stream X".

What would be the most efficient and correct way of approaching this problem?

My Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final RandomNumberStream rns = RandomNumberStream();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text('Random Number Generator',textScaleFactor:2),
          SizedBox(height:40),
          StreamBuilder<int>(
              initialData: 0,
              stream: rns.generator,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text('No Data');
                }

                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('Some error has occured');
                }
                return Text('${snapshot.data}');
              }),
          SizedBox(height: 50),
          Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
            ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Start'),
                onPressed: () {
                  rns.start();
                }),
            SizedBox(width: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Stop'),
                onPressed: () {
                  rns.stop();
                }),
          ])
        ]);
  }
}

class RandomNumberStream {
  late StreamSubscription<int> sub;
  late StreamController<int> controller;
  Random random = Random();
  
  void dispose(){
    controller.close();
  }
  
  RandomNumberStream(){
   controller = StreamController<int>.broadcast(onCancel: dispose);
  }
  
  void start() {
      sub = randomNumberGenerator().listen(streamValueHandler);
  }

  void streamValueHandler(int event) {
    controller.sink.add(event);
  }

  void stop(){
    sub.cancel();
  }
  
  Stream<int> randomNumberGenerator() async* {
    while (true) {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
      yield random.nextInt(10000);
    }
  }

  Stream<int> get generator => controller.stream;
}
```

dartpad: https://dartpad.dev/c4e45dc10a2a4244763cfb181597a233?null_safety=true

github gist: https://gist.github.com/ritvij-saxena/c4e45dc10a2a4244763cfb181597a233

The code works as expected, but I'm afraid it may not the most efficient or correct one. Requesting feedback.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Seems good but remember streams are active even when the page is not active and in background state. So you need to completely destroy the controller by setting it to null to make sure no unintended resources are used. In some stream objects like animation and alike, just shutting down stream subscription isn't enough, you need to kill the controller completely. Because if controller is active, you can expect memory leaks, and intense resource usage, etc. So, its better to destroy controller in most cases. Might as well set subscription to `null` as well for safety.

**Edit**: By the way, I just noticed that you're running this in a stateless class. I would run it inside a statefull class so you can manage the controller and subscription instances. That also allows you to call your `dispose()` method when the object is removed from widget tree.

So simple modification is:

```
void dispose(){
    sub.cancel();
    controller.close();
    sub = null; 
    controller = null; //This is important to make sure its completely inactive when page is disposed for resource and memory leak issues

}
```

Comment: Since this is under null_safety = true, then 
 late StreamSubscription<int> sub;
  late StreamController<int> controller; 

changes to
  StreamSubscription<int>? sub;
  StreamController<int>? controller;

Is there any other method, apart from using null? Also is there any method to stop randomNumberGenerator() ?. If you were to make this app, how would you re-write it?

Comment: All he has to change is `late StreamSubscription<int>? sub;` and `late StreamController<int>? controller;`

Comment: I would put it inside a Statefull class to manage its state, look at the edits I made to the answer.